# upload multiple image to pdf using fpdf php getting fatal error

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm currently im trying to set up the pdf report using fpdf that includes multiple images on it.

After googling the best solution for my problem I still can't get it right.

My code is as follows:

```
include 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['add_gambarvk']))
{
  $gambarvk_name = $_POST['gambarvk_name'];
  $gambarvk_image = $_FILES['gambarvk_image']['name'];
  $gambarvk_image_tmp_name = $_FILES['gambarvk_image']['tmp_name'];
  $size = getimagesize($gambarvk_image_tmp_name);
  $gambarvk_image_folder = './uploaded_img/' . $gambarvk_image;

  if(empty($gambarvk_name) || empty($gambarvk_image))
  {
    $message[] = 'please fill out all';
  }
  else 
  {
    // Get all the submitted data from the form
    $insert = "INSERT INTO gambarvk(name, image) VALUES('$gambarvk_name', '$gambarvk_image')";
    $upload = mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
  
    if($upload) 
    {
      //move the uploaded image into the folder: image
      move_uploaded_file($gambarvk_image_tmp_name, $gambarvk_image_folder);
      $message[] = 'Gambar berjaya dimasukkan';
    }
    else
    {
        $message[] = 'Gambar tidak berjaya dimasukkan';
    }
  }
};

$select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM gambarvk");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select))
{

  $image_format = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['gambarvk_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));  

  //function Image($file, $x=null, $y=null, $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='')

  $pdf->Image('./uploaded_img/'.$gambarvk_image,150,25,50,20, $image_format);
}
```

These errors and notices come out:

> Notice: Undefined index: gambarvk_image in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK.php on line 821
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK.php on line 821
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: gambarvk_image in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK.php on line 825
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Image file has no
> extension and no type was specified: ./uploaded_img/ in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK-fpdf\fpdf.php:267 Stack
> trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK-fpdf\fpdf.php(881):
> FPDF->Error('Image file has ...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK.php(825):
> FPDF->Image('./uploaded_img/', 150, 25, 50, 20, '') #2 {main} thrown
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK-fpdf\fpdf.php on line
> 267.

If I use file extension like PNG or JPG:

```
//function Image($file, $x=null, $y=null, $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='')

$pdf->Image('./uploaded_img.png/'.$gambarvk_image,150,25,50,20, $image_format);
```

The fatal error is changed to:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Unsupported image type:
> png/ in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK-fpdf\fpdf.php:267
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK-fpdf\fpdf.php(889):
> FPDF->Error('Unsupported ima...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK.php(825):
> FPDF->Image('./uploaded_img....', 150, 25, 50, 20, 'png/') #2 {main}
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\laporan_vk\laporanVK-fpdf\fpdf.php on
> line 267

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: Firstly your code will try to use `$_FILES['gambarvk_image']['name']` in all cases, not just when `if(isset($_POST['add_gambarvk']))` is true. So this means it will probably try to read it at times when you haven't submitted the form.

Comment: Therefore you should move the `$select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM gambarvk");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select))
{

  $image_format = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['gambarvk_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));  

  //function Image($file, $x=null, $y=null, $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='')

  $pdf->Image('./uploaded_img/'.$gambarvk_image,150,25,50,20, $image_format);
}` code _inside_ the `if(isset($_POST['add_gambarvk']))` block, to prevent that.

Comment: Secondly: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: hai ADyson thank for your guidance.